# I'm confusing with the execution order of Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I nest a Promise Object into resolve(), I was literally confusing with the output.

```js
new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res(1);
}) // the first
    .then(value => {
        console.log(value);
        return 2;
    })
    .then(value => {
        console.log(value);
        return 3;
    })
    .then(value => {
        console.log(value);
        return 4;
    })
    .then(value => {
        console.log(value);
    });

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(7);
        }),
    );
}).then(value => {
    console.log(value);
});
```

The output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcfeD.png)

I can't understand why 7 was output after the 3, who can explain this for me? Thinks.

Comment: You're question is basically about macro-task scheduling (if you were looking for search terms)